# "Upgrade Ubuntu 13.04 to Ubuntu 13.10" is greyed out

Tags: upgrade, system-installation, ubiquity

I booted from a Live USB, however when trying to upgrade the upgrade option is greyed out. Additionally, the installer reports that there is no internet ([asked here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/408991/ubuntu-installer-says-no-internet-even-though-i-do-have-internet)).

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading from the install medium is only available if you have internet access during the install.

source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1170531

> It is correct, we do not support offline upgrades via ubiquity/desktop CDs.

So as long as the installer detects there is no internet connection this will be grayed out. After your other question with the missing internet connection is solved this won't be grayed out anymore.

Answer (score 0):

this is not windows.
Boot the system, backup your files, and then run:

do-release-upgrade

David.